# influxDB Internal Server Error at new ServiceNotAvailableError

Tags: node.js, database, time-series, influxdb

I am trying to save price data as it comes in. When I try to save the results of one product in real time then I do not get any errors. When I add more products I get the following error thrown when calling db.writePoints(...).

```
 Error saving data to InfluxDB! Error: Internal Server Error
 at new ServiceNotAvailableError (/media/kareem/09F434A51ACAE825/cryptoTrading/data/dataGatherers/server/node_modules/influx/lib/src/pool.js:37:28)
 at /media/kareem/09F434A51ACAE825/cryptoTrading/data/dataGatherers/server/node_modules/influx/lib/src/pool.js:272:49
 at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/media/kareem/09F434A51ACAE825/cryptoTrading/data/dataGatherers/server/node_modules/influx/lib/src/pool.js:79:13)
 at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
 at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
 at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
 at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (_http_client.js:551:21)
 at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:115:23)  
 at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:440:20)
 at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
```

I am not sure what is causing this error or how to get more information. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Q:** I am not sure what is causing this error or how to get more information. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**A:** Looking at your `stacktrace`, the exception `ServiceNotAvailableError` seem to suggests that your `influxdb` is rejecting the writes for some reason. Therefore the first thing I would dig for more information would be through `influxdb`'s logs.

I also did a quick research on your behalf and it seems like there is a bug related to this at `influxdb`'s github issue page. See [**here**](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/8582)

Probably try upgrading your `influxdb` to the latest release or at least to a version which include that link's fixes.